# Перенаправление локального траффика на удаленный адрес

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, route

*Привет. Вчера задавал похожий вопрос, но оказалось, что исходные данные не те.*

Есть linux-железка greenbox, у которой есть 4 eth-порта (см. картинку), каждая имеет свой адрес в своей подсети. К каждому из портов подключено по другой железке blackbox, каждая из которых имеет один и тот же адрес (192.168.0.30), и мы не имеем к ней доступа, мы можем только к ней обращаться по сети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На greenbox у нас есть доступ, там полноценный линукс и там же крутится приложение, которое должно общаться с 4-мя адресами.

Задача заключается в том, чтобы организовать перенаправление всего локального траффика с локального адреса на удаленный (192.168.0.30). Речь идет о траффике от приложения.

Я думал о том, чтобы назначить каждому порту alias и перенаправлять траффик с каждого из них на 192.168.0.30 с помощью iptables. Но не выходит. Пробовал перенаправить в тестовых целях хотя бы порт от алиса к удаленному адресу, например, создал алиас на eth0(192.168.1.100) с адресом 192.168.0.1:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.30:4444
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.30 --dport 4444 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
```

Но не выходит, пакеты не уходят на удаленный хост.
(Роутинг включен)

Comment: например, можно [воспользоваться netns-ами](https://serverfault.com/a/706274/292034)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin стыдно, но даже не слышал о netns. Попробую разобраться, спасибо. Если поможет, то оформите коммент ответом.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin действительно, с помощью namespaces можно развязать интерфейсы с одинаковыми адресами. Осталось понять, подходит ли это под требования прикладного приложения, я обязательно отпишусь позже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз прямых ответов, связанных с iptables не последовало, то опубликую решение, подсказанное @alexanderbarakin, с помощью network namespaces.

Решение состоит в том, чтобы для каждого интерфейса создать собственное сетевое пространство имен, изолированное от остальных.

```
# создать для интерфейса новый namespace
ip netns add netX
# добавить интерфейс в namespace
ip link set dev ethX netns netX
# поднять интерфейс
ip netns exec netX ip link set dev ethX up
# назначить интерфейсу один и тот же IP-адрес!
ip netns exec netX ip address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev ethX
```

В итоге мы можем запускать команды в выбранном изолированном namespace, а также наше приложение

```
ip netns exec netX <command>
```

В итоге, каждая команда будет видеть только выбранный нами интерфейс с адресом 192.168.0.1 и, соответственно, общаться с хостом, подключенным только к этому интерфейсу.